# Отобрать значения по ключу и перезаписать

Tags: php, массивы, key

Как сделать, чтобы у $mas 0 и 3 ключ заменились на 'null'?

```
$result = array(1,2);
$mas = array("Нулевой", "Первый", "Второй", "Третий");
foreach ($result as $row) {

    if ($row != array_search($mas[$row], $mas)) {
    $mas[$row];
    } else {
    $mas[$row] = 'null';
    }
}
print_r($mas);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array(1, 2);
$mas = array("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three");
foreach ($mas as $key=>$row) {
    if(!in_array($key, $result)){
        $mas[$key] = 'null';
    }
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($mas);
print '</pre>';
```